# MS Access and SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to report out my query, but I get a

> Syntax error in JOIN operation

Any suggestions as to how I should properly set my parentheses?

```
select 
    v.VendorID, v.Name,
    CCur(Format(sum(p.ListPrice * (1 - sp.DiscountPercent) * od.OrderQuantity), "0.00")) as Sales,
    sum(p.ListPrice-p.Cost) as Profit,
    sum(od.OrderQuantity) as Quantitiy, 
    sum(sp.DiscountPercent) as Discounts
from 
    ((((vendor v
join 
    product p on v.VendorID = p.VendorID)
join 
    OrderDetail od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID)
join 
    OrderHeader oh on od.OrderID = oh.OrderID)
join 
    SalesPromotion sp on od.SalesPromotionID = sp.SalesPromotionID)
where 
    year(oh.OrderDate) = 2014
group by 
    v.VendorID, v.Name
order by 
    Sales desc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fix the error?

```
FROM (((Vendor v
JOIN Product p ON v.VendorID = p.VendorID)
JOIN OrderDetail od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID)
JOIN OrderHeader oh ON od.OrderID = oh.OrderID)
JOIN SalesPromotion sp ON od.SalesPromotionID = sp.SalesPromotionID
```